# Unity Dropdown with Image

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do I make a dropdown like this one? The sprite in the Options doesn't produce the coin.

[image]

Comment: What about passing "new GUIContent(sprite)"? Can't test atm, but it sure takes images in the constructor, though not sure about EditorGUI methods being able to draw it.

Comment: Assuming we're talking EditorGUI here (and Options you mentioned are  "displayedOptions[]" parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a way actually on how to this **drop down** thing . This is my way of doing it . Maybe this can help you achieve what you want.

1.) Put all your gold coin with star in the right positions something like that on the picture you showed.

2.) Adjust the alpha using the timer so its something like this

```
timer = 5f;
void Update(){
    timer -= Time.DeltaTime();
    if(timer < 4f){
        //adjust alpha here
    }
  //and so on...
}
```

Something like that.